# How to put array values in different columns of same row of csv

Tags: php

I am having an array having multiple elements and i want each element to be inserted in a column of the same row of a csv file using php.
I am trying hard but can't find the solution can anyone help me please as soon as possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function [fputcsv](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php) can do the job.

Comment: That's pretty simple :
`$fp = fopen('your.csv','a'); fputcsv($fp, $your_array); fclose($fp);`

By default it uses the delimiter `,` and the enclosure `"`, but you can change that with the 3rd et 4th parameter of this fonction.